# How do I set onListItemClick here?

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I apologize if this is a really basic question but how do I set onListItemClick, if I got the list items from a textfile on a server? What I want to do is just display a toast when the item on listview is clicked, but I can't seem to add in onListItemClick to do this. I think it's because of the try/catch ?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListView extends ListActivity {
    public String[] ListItems = new String[]{};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        URL textUrl;
        try {
            textUrl = new URL("http://172.30.54.153/databases/result.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
            String StringBuffer;
            String stringText = "";
            stringText.split(",");
            while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringText += StringBuffer;
            }
            String DbLines = new String(stringText);
            ListItems = DbLines.split(",");

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListItems));
            bufferReader.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void OnListItemClick(ListView Parent,View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "y"+ ListItems[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u getting any error in logcat?

Comment: did you add list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01); for your list view?

Comment: ListActivity named ListView that contains a ListView. You should consider renaming your Activity to avoid type mismatch and ambiguous naming issues.

Comment: I would check that your list items are being loaded properly first. Also, move the `bufferedReader.close()` into a `finally` block. Move `setListAdapter(...)` outside the `try-catch-finally block`.

Comment: omg thanks you guys i managed to get it working by following Karakuri's answer, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues:

**First**, your private event listener's handler was in **`private`**, so it's no longer the inherited methods, your code is wrong with the **`private`**:

```
private void OnListItemClick(ListView Parent,View v, int position, long id)
```

You must use widen the function scope for overriding methods, means **public** or **protected**. Suggest, you should use @Override identifier to ensure your inheritance intention. Modify your code like this (with @Override and protected or public):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
....
}
```

see the SDK guide:
[ListActivity.onListItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29)

**Second**, You must make your listview to listen to click events:

Change your class definition:

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener 
{
...
}
```

And add following code in **`onCreate()`**. This lines will register the current list activity (this) with the specified listener:

```
this.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your onCreate:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "y"+ ListItems[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

and remove this:

```
private void OnListItemClick(ListView Parent,View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(this, "y"+ ListItems[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

You might want to rename your class to something like MyListView to avoid confusion

Comment: You can't call `setOnItemClickListener` on a `ListActivity`.

Comment: You can but you need to get the ListView first and it doesn't make much sense to add a listener to something that has a built in listener.

Answer (score 0):

Lint at OnListItemClick
`The method OnListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) from the type ListActivity is never used locally`

Replace it with this:
`protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`
That is `onListItemClick` - `on` lowercase not `OnListItemClick` - `On` uppercase


Hope this help!